# xcconfig file -- set a variable value with a leading space?

Tags: xcode, unix, xcconfig

Suppose I want to define the value of an environment variable BAR to be " foo", without the quotes.  If my .xcconfig file has the line

```
BAR = foo
```

that will set it to "foo".  Same goes if it has the line

```
BAR =  foo
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Did you try `BAR = " foo"` ?

Comment: yeah, it kept the quotes in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

```
EMPTY_STRING =
BAR = $(EMPTY_STRING) foo // the empty string protects leading space.
```

Comment: BAR = $() foo has the same result. No need to define an extra variable